# What is the main weakness of a zoolock-deck?

Tags: hearthstone

Nowadays many players across all ranks seem to play a [zoolock](http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/35326-budget-reynads-zoo-v2-warlock-aggro)-deck. The concept behind this deck is just overrunning your oppenent with low-mana-minions in the early game and then finishing him off with a doomguard or leeroy. As a warlock can lifetap nearly every turn, he always has twice as much cards as every other class, so he does never run out of cards (even if he plays card-burn-cards like soulfire or doomguard).

For me it seems like this is a deck without a major weakness, but I think/hope that I am overseeing something. So my question is: What is the main weakness of such an aggressive rush-deck (besides from maybe facing another zoolock)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few that comes to mind.

- **Board clears/AOE**: obviously when you have a lot of low mana weenie creatures, they are highly susecptible to board clears.  I've started to bring 2 Wild Pyromancers into every deck just for those situations.  Each class have their own way of doing board clears but they are all quite effective at killing the minions.  Zoolocks typically counter this by packing lots of divine shielded minions, so I also started packing a blood knight into my decks for this purpose.
- **High Health Taunters**: With only limited hard removals, if you put out enough taunts then he will lose a lot of minions in trying to remove your taunter.  5+ hp taunters is best since it can survive a soulfire.
- **Weapons**: You can limit his board control by clearing out his weenie creatures via attacks.  This isn't for all classes but rogues and warriors excel in this regard.

As an aside, abdomination does both #1 and #2 so it is especially good against zoolock.

Comment: The best part about the wild pyromancer is that you can deal the damage in two steps, first burst to get rid of divine shields, 2nd to kill all their 1 toughness minions.

Comment: Adding a Stampeding Kodo or two also helps. I never liked the card much, but vs zoo it's almost always a two to one trade.

Comment: As a paladin, Wild Pyro + Equality kills everything except minions with divine shield. But Wild Pyro + Another spell (even the coin!) + Equality kills EVERYTHING (barring minions summoned by deathrattle or paladin resurrection). It works wonders against these zoolock decks. (And Equality + Consecration or Wild Pyro + Consecration are both acceptable fallback scenarios if you're not drawing either the pyro or the equality)